# Have I unnecessarily introduced the need to compile this legacy Classic ASP project?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I was tasked with introducing some new functionality into a legacy system which would be a great cost saving to the business.

An initial investigation revealed it was a Classic ASP project written with VB. Not being overly experienced with Classic ASP I researched if I could use ASP.Net for my additions and found they work together quite nicely. I introduced some simple new functionality, completed some initial tests and confident it would work set about the remainder of the project.

During development I found that I couldn't access data set in the `Application_OnStart` event of the `global.asa` file from my .ASPX pages and as a workaround I created a `Global.asax` file which sets the same values on the `Application_Start` event. This has meant a little configuration duplication / loss of DRYness since these files contain the database details rather than reading them in from a separate config file (these in essence ARE the config files) which was deemed an acceptable trade-off for time saved separating them out.

However, in moving from our DEV to our UAT environment I'm now finding that changes in the `global.asa` file on the UAT server are reflected immediately whilst changes in the `Global.asax` file require a recompile and redeploy of the .dll to take effect. Changes to .aspx pages are reflected immediately with no need to recompile.

Is this always the case or have I inadvertently introduced this issue during the setup and development of the project? If so can you explain how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP and ASP.net are different technologies, but you can use them in the same website (in the same way you can use Classic ASP and PHP in the same website if you really want to).  One consequence of this - as you have discovered - is that each needs its own database connection.  Another which frustrates many people is that session variables created in Classic pages are invisible to .net pages and vice versa.

As you have also discovered, Classic uses code which is executed at runtime while .net uses compiled code.  The need to recompile the project following changes is part and parcel of ASP.net development.

I should also mention that Classic uses VBScript.  This is a similar, but not identical language to VB, or VB.net

Classic ASP is regarded as "legacy" - if you're unfamiliar with it then it makes sense to add any new functionality in a technology with which you are more familiar

Comment: Thank for the response. Interesting reading with some good points to keep in mind however this doesn't address why I can alter the .aspx pages without the need for a re-compile and seems to suggest I shouldn't be able to. Are you able to explain that or even provide links to resources you find useful that I can search for an explanation myself?

Comment: You would probably need to describe your development environment.  Typically with an asp.net project you just upload the dll, you keep the source files (the code behinds) locally

Comment: This link may be of interest
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks John, I was attempting to keep the question short and as 'bare bones' as possible. It could (and likely is) related to my development environment but without it being narrowed down a bit I could have ended up including a lot of exteronous information about my env. that just drowned the question / key issue. I'll review your link and update the question with more specifics where I can.